# What is default timeout in WebView in Android?

Tags: android-webview

**I am not asking how to provide a timeout for Android WebView.**

What is a default timeout in Android `WebView`. For example, if I load URL in `WebView` and there is no network connectivity, for How long will it wait BY DEFAULT before throwing `ERROR_TIMEOUT`?

Or there is no default?

Comment: There is no such documentation available to state the exact timeout for the android webview. But from http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide/platforms/android/config.html#Android%20Configuration documentation it might be 20 seconds.

Comment: @KingofMasses actually i need that value to validate the unit test case. for example: if a web view is not loaded in "default" timeout sec. fail that test case.

Comment: This seems to be deeply embedded inside androids source code. I'm browsing around in the android source code and it [seems to get a different error code from an internal library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/master/Source/WebKit/android/WebCoreSupport/WebViewClientError.cpp#64). Not sure though.

Comment: Also, I think there are 2 timeouts: the connect and the response timeout. Don't know how WebKit handles them though.

Comment: @AADTechnical I don't quite get why you'd want to test the time the WebView takes to load. Also, if there is no network connectivity, I think the WebView won't even try to load, and fail pretty much immediately.

Comment: did you find an answer? or does it just depend on the network layer throwing the timeout and webview doesn't enforce a timeout on top of that at all? on a localhost server if the tcp connection is opened(response timeout case) it seems to be happy to wait even 10+ minutes before the request is answered, though perhaps that doesn't count as a timeout. I'm trying to research and test how dependable this behavior is.

Answer (score -4):

For android timeout , if you are using cordova then refer to [@king of masses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741724/what-is-default-timeout-in-webview-in-android/comment-70343526) comment.

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

to set the timeout then try to use

```
super.getIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 0);
```

The first argument is the property name and the second is the default value which in this case is `0`.

Hope this helps,

Comment: i am not using cordova. my Q is for native webview class in Android SDk